# SOAP in PHP - Multiple Parameters Help Needed

Tags: php, soap

I have some xml soap data and within the PurchaseOrderNumbers area I can't get the strings to work right.

```
POST /services/trevco.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: b2b.trevcoinc.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://trevcoinc.com/GetOrderStatus"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <soap:Body>
<GetOrderStatus xmlns="http://trevcoinc.com/">
  <request>
    <APIKey>string</APIKey>
    <APIPasscode>string</APIPasscode>
    <PurchaseOrderNumbers>
      <string>string</string>
      <string>string</string>
    </PurchaseOrderNumbers>
    <PONumber>string</PONumber>
  </request>
</GetOrderStatus>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Here is some sample php code I tried

```
$client_trevco = new SoapClient(
    "url",
    array('APIKey' => "", 'APIPasscode' => "")
);

$xml = array(
    'PurchaseOrderNumbers' => array(
        'string' => array(
            array( "GC-0998" )
        )
    )
);

$results = $client_trevco->__call("GetOrderStatus", $xml);

print_r($results->GetItemListResult);
```

and the error I get

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Server] Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that following the flow of the XML, So simple that i overlooked it.

**Correct code**

```
$orderNumbers = array('0998', '1001');

$arr = array("request" => array("APIKey" => '', "APIPasscode" => '', 'PurchaseOrderNumbers' => array('string' => $orderNumbers)));

$client_trevco = new SoapClient("https://b2b.trevcoinc.com/services/trevco.asmx?wsdl");

$sa = $client_trevco->GetOrderStatus($arr);

<GetOrderStatus xmlns="http://trevcoinc.com/">
  <request>
    <APIKey>string</APIKey>
    <APIPasscode>string</APIPasscode>
    <PurchaseOrderNumbers>
      <string>string</string>
      <string>string</string>
    </PurchaseOrderNumbers>
    <PONumber>string</PONumber>
  </request>
</GetOrderStatus>
```